# Pseudo element not showing in React on paragraph tag despite using display block

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

This pseudo element `::after` won't show up in my browser at all. I am using React.js and Material UI `makeStyles`.

This is the code:

```
modalTitle: {
    borderBottom: '2px solid red',
    display: 'block',
    margin: '10px 15px',
    padding: '0',
    width: '100px',

    '&::after': {
        background: 'green',
        content: '',
        display: 'block',
        height: '2px',
        width: '2px',
    },
},
```

Note that the code below `modalTitle` shows up and works, only the pseudo element doesn't go through. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one. When you use `makeStyles`, it accepts a styles object (or a function that returns an object). This object has the class names as keys and objects containing attribute-value pairs as values. These values are strings (like `"block"`, `"green"`, or `"10px 15px"`).

The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements in CSS allows us to insert content onto the page. Every pseudo-element must have a CSS `content` property, without it the default value of content is set to `normal`/`none`, and no content is displayed.

The problem with your code is that you add `content: ''` in your object, but you need to pass an empty string as the CSS value, like this: `content: '""'`.

Similarly, if you want to insert some text using `content` you can't simply add the string, you need to use quotes around the text and pass it as a string:

```
// ❌ this one doesn't work
{
  content: 'some text',
}

// ✅ this one does work
{
  content: '"some text"',
}
```

So, you can use the following and it will add the element:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  modalTitle: {
    borderBottom: '2px solid red',
    display: 'block',
    margin: '10px 15px',
    padding: '0',
    width: '100px',

    '&::after': {
      background: 'green',
      content: '""',
      display: 'block',
      height: '2px',
      width: '2px',
    },
  },
});
```